# Bash terminal auto complete + history on script

Tags: bash, macos

I have a bash script (bash version 3) and I have a prompt in this script. I wish to have in this prompt with history (when a press an arrow) and the autocomplete (as a normal terminal).

I have these 2 functions:

- One for autocomplete:

```
#!/bin/bash

autocomplete_input() {
    local -r opts=( "$@" )
    (
        readonly temp=$(mktemp -d /tmp/myreadline.XXXX)
        cd "$temp"
        trap "rm -rf $temp" EXIT
        touch "${opts[@]}"
        read -e -p "Type a command: " input # I wish to have autocompletition here
        printf '%s\n' "$input"
    )
}

while true; do
    echo "Menu:"
    echo "1. car"
    echo "2. dog"
    echo "3. dollars"
    echo "4. Quit"

    
    input=$(autocomplete_input "car" "dog" "dollars" "quit")

  
    case $input in
        luna)
            echo "You have selected car."
            ;;
        sole)
            echo "You have selected dog."
            ;;
        libra)
            echo "You have selected dollars."
            ;;
        quit)
            echo "You have selected quit"
            exit 0
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Error command"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

- another one for history:

```
function prompt {
  while IFS= read -er -p "t!care>> " command; do
    history -s "$command"
    run_command "$command"
  done
}
```

but I'm not able to merge them.

I wish that the script works on unix system like Ubuntu and MacOs.

Comment: I have used only English now.

Comment: what do you mean by "merge them"?

Comment: I wish to have a prompt on my script in order to have:
- history (by arrows)
- auto complite command
-